# Identify how many times Widget has been viewed by unique users

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to programming and learning by building small projects. I'm building a widget where users add a snippet of code onto their website and widget appear.

3 of my friends have added it on their website and now they have asked me to show them how many unique people viewed the widget.

I'm not able to figure out how to do it.

I thought of taking count of get request made to fetch widget data but then if the same person calls widget 100 times, it's not unique users but same user 10O times.

I want to build it privacy-friendly so can someone help me a way to do this.

I referred to an open source project to build the widget and it is loaded onto website like this. This code is written by the author, since I don't understand Typescript, I didn't touch this page.

```
import { Configurations } from './models';

type MethodNames = 'init' | 'event';
export const DEFAULT_NAME = '_hw';




/**
 * Represents a model that is created in embedded script
 * as part of script initialization.
 */
interface LoaderObject {
    /**
     * Queue that accumulates method calls during downloading
     * and loading of widget's script file.
     */
    q: Array<[MethodNames, {}]>;
}

/**
 * Loads widget instance.
 *
 * @param win Global window object which stores pre-loaded and post-loaded state of widget instance.
 * @param defaultConfig A configurations that are merged with user.
 * @param scriptElement The script tag that includes installation script and triggered loader.
 * @param render A method to be called once initialization done and DOM element for hosting widget is ready.
 */
export default (
    win: Window,
    defaultConfig: Configurations,
    scriptElement: Element | null,
    render: (element: HTMLElement, config: Configurations) => void
) => {

    // get a hold of script tag instance, which has an
    // attribute `id` with unique identifier of the widget instance
    const instanceName =
        scriptElement?.attributes.getNamedItem('id')?.value ?? DEFAULT_NAME;
    const loaderObject: LoaderObject = win[instanceName];
    if (!loaderObject || !loaderObject.q) {
        throw new Error(
            `Widget didn't find LoaderObject for instance [${instanceName}]. ` +
                `The loading script was either modified, no call to 'init' method was done ` +
                `or there is conflicting object defined in \`window.${instanceName}\` .`
        );
    }


    // check that the widget is not loaded twice under the same name
    if (win[`loaded-${instanceName}`]) {
        throw new Error(
            `Widget with name [${instanceName}] was already loaded. ` +
                `This means you have multiple instances with same identifier (e.g. '${DEFAULT_NAME}')`
        );
    }

    // this will an root element of the widget instance
    let targetElement: HTMLElement;

  


    // iterate over all methods that were called up until now
    for (let i = 0; i < loaderObject.q.length; i++) {
        const item = loaderObject.q[i];
        const methodName = item[0];
   
        if (i === 0 && methodName !== 'init') {
            throw new Error(
                `Failed to start Widget [${instanceName}]. 'init' must be called before other methods.`
            );
        } else if (i !== 0 && methodName === 'init') {
            continue;
        }
         

        switch (methodName) {
            case 'init':

                const loadedObject = Object.assign(defaultConfig, item[1]);
               
                // the actual rendering of the widget
                const wrappingElement =
                    loadedObject.element ?? win.document.body;
                targetElement = wrappingElement.appendChild(
                    win.document.createElement('div')
                );
                targetElement.setAttribute('id', `widget-${instanceName}`);
                render(targetElement, loadedObject);

                // store indication that widget instance was initialized
                win[`loaded-${instanceName}`] = true;



                break;
            // TODO: here you can handle additional async interactions
            // with the widget from page (e.q. `_hw('refreshStats')`)
            default:
                console.warn(`Unsupported method [${methodName}]`, item[1]);
        }

    }

  

    // once finished processing all async calls, we going
    // to convert LoaderObject into sync calls to methods
    win[instanceName] = (method: MethodNames, ...args: any[]) => {
        switch (method) {
            case 'event': {
                targetElement?.dispatchEvent(
                    new CustomEvent('widget-event', {
                        detail: { name: args?.[0] },
                    })
                );
                break;
            }
            default:
                console.warn(`Unsupported method [${method}]`, args);
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: `I thought of taking count of get request made to fetch widget data but then if the same person calls widget 100 times, it's not unique users but same user 10O times` you could store the IP of the requester.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can try this. 

Btw, is there any other way to fix this problem as well?